# Rspec: How to write conditional validation when it also works with validate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, rspec-rails

My Location model which can have a website. The website only has to be present if the location is online. Before it is saved, the website must have the correct format.

**location.rb**

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :online :website
  validates_presence_of :website, :if => 'online.present?'
  validates_inclusion_of :online, :in => [true, false]
  validate :website_has_correct_format, :if => 'website.present?'

  private

  def website_has_correct_format
    unless self.website.blank?
      unless self.website.downcase.start_with?('https://', 'http://')
        errors.add(:website, 'The website must be in its full format.)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I make a spec to test for this:

**location_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Location do

  before(:each) do
    @location = FactoryGirl.build(:location)
  end

  subject { @location }

  describe 'when website is not present but store is online' do
    before { @location.website = '' && @location.online = true }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

The test fails, bringing to me the error:

```
Failures:

  1) Location when website is not present but store is online
     Failure/Error: it { should_not be_valid }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `downcase' for true:TrueClass
     #./app/models/location.rb:82:in `website_has_correct_format'
     #./spec/models/location_spec.rb:72:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your spec file is written a little bit wrong.  The `&&` is not working the way you expect it to.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Location do

  before(:each) do
    @location = FactoryGirl.build(:location)
  end

  subject { @location }

  describe 'when website is not present but store is online' do
    before do
      @location.website = ''
      @location.online = true
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

Comment: OK, so now it's passing. Thank you.